# Inner Json Blob should be converted to Map<String, String>

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I have the following JSON Structure

```
"parent": {                   
   "method": "PUT",                
   "uri": "/path",                 
   "child": {“key1”: “value1”, “key2”: "value2”: “key3”, “value3”}                      
 }
```

and Moshi Models in kotlin

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class parent(
    val uri: String,
    val method: String,
    val child: Child?
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Child(
    val key1: String?
    val key2: String?
    val key3: String?
     . . .
     . . .
)
```

For the above Json blob and corresponding Moshi backed model classes. I want to convert child into Map type  rather than Chid type coz the content of child could be any number of key value e Pair.

So this is what I want

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class parent(
    val uri: String,
    val method: String,
    val child: Map<String, String>?
)
```

How should this be done in moshi?

Comment: Doesn't that work already?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nicolas
It's already supported by default.